# PHP - Email form is sending over 50 mails after form submit

Tags: php, email

I have a problem that after I fill out the contact form on my HTML website I receive over 50 same E-mails. Its a HTML form connected to contact.php file which code is shown bellow. I have set everything but maybe there is a problem in my code or somewhere else.

My code is over here

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+ (ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone   = $_POST['phone'];
$subject  = $_POST['subject'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$verify   = $_POST['verify'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Vyplnte meno.</div>';
exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Vyplnte email.</div>';
exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
echo '<div class="error_message">Zadali ste nesprávny e-mail, skúste to znovu.</div>';
exit();
}

if(trim($comments) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Vyplnte text správy.</div>';
exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";


$address = "noreply@marcelaskolenia.sk";
$address = "lubosmasura@gmail.com";
$toCustomer = $email;
// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'Mate novu spravu od ' . $name . '.';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "Mate novu spravu od $name." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$subject\"" . "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "Kontaktujte $name cez email, $email alebo cez mobil $phone";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers .= 'To: Test <noreply@marcelaskolenia.sk>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Testk <noreply@marcelaskolenia.sk>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

// Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

echo "<fieldset>";
echo "<div id='success_page'>";
echo "<h3 class'mark'>Sprava bola odoslana.</h3>";
echo "<p>Dakujeme <strong>$name</strong>, Vasa sprava nam bude dorucena.</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

echo 'ERROR!';


}
```

HTML code

```
  <div class="contact_form">
                        <div id="message"></div>
                        <form id="contactform" class="row" action="contact.php" name="contactform" method="post">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Meno">
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefónne číslo">
                            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Predmet">
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="comments" id="comments" rows="6" placeholder="Text správy"></textarea>
                            <button type="submit" value="SEND" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> ODOSLAŤ</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- end col -->
```

Any Ideas why is this happening?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you showing us all? There seems to be some loop we do not see

Comment: For one thing, the leading dot in this `$headers .= 'To: Test <noreply@marcelaskolenia.sk>' . "\r\n";` needs to be removed.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner tht doesnt make it x50. .. I think this code is inside some loop

Comment: @Ingus yes this is the contact.php everything else is HTML but there is nothing in it only contact form connected to this file contact.php

Comment: @Ingus I know that but that would have thrown an error about it. I don't think they're telling/showing us everything. That was meant as a sort of a side note.

Comment: Before instead of headers to and reply was this code

`$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;`

But It does not work when Its like that, then form is not being sent.

Comment: Do you send with ajax? and applied like 50 event handlers?, check network tab if your using ajax.

Comment: I have updted the question with HTML

Comment: @LawrenceCherone no Ajax there

Comment: I can only suggest strip out everything and call `mail()` once manually with hard coded values, if you still get 50 emails then the mta is to blame, though not sure how that could happen. Your php code is not sending 50 emails if you have no loops or includes

Comment: got any forwards setup?, most smtp providers prevent infinite relaying like if you send to a@example.com and it forward to a@example.com and that forwards back to a@example.com, could be a couple of things but is not the code shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221272/discussion-between-lubo-masura-and-lawrence-cherone).

Comment: Another thing i could think of. .. Maybe. .. Just maybe there are some wierd redirect for that email address?